# Dynamic List using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

my website is comugg.com. Im trying to make a dynamic dropdown according to this portion of my website.

https://gyazo.com/bc68919205d61b2022543d1aef81ca36

Anyways i got the first and 2nd level to work. Im struggling on my third level. i've narrowed the problem down to these two areas within my code. If anyone can give me a second eye on this i would appreciate it.

```
        <div id="model">
    <label>Model</label>
        <select name="model" id="modellist" onchange="getId2(this.value);">
            <option value="">Select Model</option>
        </select>
    </div>

            <div id="year">
    <label>Year</label>
        <select name="year" id="yearlist" >
            <option value="">Select Year</option>
        </select>
    </div>


    <script>
        function getId(val){
                jQuery.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "getdata.php",
                data: "make="+val,
                success:function(data){
                    jQuery("#modellist").html(data);
                }
                });


        }
        function getId2(val){
                jQuery.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "getdata2.php",
                data: "model="+val,
                success:function(data){
                    jQuery("#yearlist").html(data);
                }
                });

        }

    </script>
```

and the next part of the getdata2.php is

```
<?php
include_once "connection.php";
$make = $_POST["year"];


if (!empty($_POST["year"])) {
    $make = $_POST["year"];
    echo $query = "SELECT Distinct Year FROM websitemasterlist where Model='".$model."'"; 
    $results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    ?>
    <option value="">Select Year</option>
    <?php
    foreach ($results as $info){
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $info["Year"]; ?>"><?php echo $info["Year"]; ?></option>
    <?php
    }
}
?>
```

any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: where is `$model`?

Comment: that is a very good question i will update the code

Comment: that fixed the problem. thank you akin. being tired really messes up how meticulate i am-.-

Comment: awesome stuff!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i do not see any year post data so update this code , hope it will work, in ajax code you use post data as

```
data: "model="+val,
```

so in your php code need to use same post value

```
if (!empty($_POST["model"])) {
    $make = $_POST["model"];
    echo $query = "SELECT Distinct Year FROM websitemasterlist where Model='".$make."'"; 
    $results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    ?>
    <option value="">Select Year</option>
    <?php
    foreach ($results as $info){
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $info["Year"]; ?>"><?php echo $info["Year"]; ?></option>
    <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that my variables were in the wrong area.